# Reliability of 4 SSD in RAID 0 -vs.-SSD Boot+5440 HDD - in laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, raid, computer-building

**Question**:  What are the benefits of SSD RAID 0 over SSD boot with 5400 HDD?

**Goal**: Decision between internal storage options

**Needs**:
Ability to seamlessly use multiple graphics and coding programs simultaneously.
Reliability of data in between backups - considering it is a mobile laptop.

**Options being considered:**
 4x 256mb SSD in RAID 0  -vs.- 512mb SSD mSATA boot + 512mb 5400 HDD
(Single large SSD is not an option available.)

**Questions**:

- Assuming reliability is more important than speed, is there a benefit to the RAID 0 arrangement over the SSD boot with regular HDD?
- Acknowledging that RAID 0 has no redundancy, my reliability question hinges on the fact there are 4 disk drives versus two. SSD reliability in comparison with HDD seems to be not very different.
- When a disk fails in 1 SSD among 4 in RAID 0, does it risk damaging data on the other 3?  Loss of 25% rather than loss of 100%?
- When an disk fails in the SSD (or HDD) of a SSD + HDD, does it only lose data on that disk?  50% vs 100?
- In these cases, would 2 drives always be better than 4?

(My primary question is comparison of reliability of arrangements.  I was unable to find a comparison of this combination elsewhere.)

Comment: Nothing is 100% reliable. Always have backups.

Comment: When 1 drive in RAID 0 dies, you lose the volume containing your data.  So 4 drives in RAID 0 is 4 times more likely to fail (and data lost) than a single drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Assuming reliability is more important than speed,** is there a benefit to the RAID 0 arrangement over the SSD boot with regular HDD?

**NO!** *RAID 0 is striping without parity or redundancy.* If any of the constituent devices in a RAID 0 array fails, then the entire array fails and cannot be accessed by normal means. It won't really "damage" the other devices, but you won't be able to get anything useful out of them by normal means either. Since you have four times the number of devices in the four-device array, as [techie007](https://superuser.com/users/23133/techie007) also pointed out your total failure odds instantly at least quadruples (possibly more, since you have four devices hooked up to the same power and data buses).

RAID 0 provides *speed and/or storage space advantages, at the cost of reliability.* If you want *reliability,* then you need to use something else.

It doesn't matter whether the constituent devices are solid-state or spinning-rust storage devices; RAID 0 is still RAID 0. A RAID 0 array fails if any constituent device fails or becomes unavailable; period.

If you want reliability beyond what a single device can offer, then your best choice on a laptop is probably mirroring. Mirroring also has the potential to increase your read performance, as any read can be satisfied equally by any constituent device. RAID 5 or 6 would work as well but require at least 3 or 4 devices to provide any benefit, and have their own potential problems (think RAID write hole).